# Dimension-wise logical indexing in a 3D array

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, bsxfun

Say I have an array `stack` of dimensions NxMxR. I would like to use logical indexing on a given dimension to update its value, without the use of a temporary variable.

Example using the temporary variable:

```
for k=1:R
    temp=stack(:,:,k);
    temp(temp<max(max(temp))/2)=NaN;
    cropped(:,:,k)=temp;
end
```

Note that it would be trivial if the condition was the same for the entire array, but it varies along the `R` dimension. `bsxfun` would be appropriate if I just wanted to subtract the threshold value in a syntax like:

```
cropped = bsxfun(@minus, stack, max(max(stack, [], 3))/2);
```

I find the use of the temporary variable clumsy and can't find a proper way of defining the function for `bsxfun` to do what the loop does.

Does anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: you have a bug with the `=NaN` part...

Comment: @natan correct, even clumsier. Thanks.

Comment: in short, you have a 3d array and you want to edit every 2d slice such that NaN replaces the values<max/2 of that slice?

Comment: @natan that is correct, or another operation using the values of a given slice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stack(bsxfun(@minus, stack, max(max(stack))/2) < 0) = NaN;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `bsxfun` implementation -

```
t1 = reshape(stack,size(stack,1)*size(stack,2),[])
t1(bsxfun(@lt,t1,max(t1)/2))=NaN
cropped = reshape(t1,size(stack))
```

One more -

```
t1 = max(reshape(stack,size(stack,1)*size(stack,2),[]))
stack(bsxfun(@lt,stack,permute(t1/2,[3 1 2])))=NaN
```

And more that is dangerously close to [Luis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23896368/3293881) -

```
stack(bsxfun(@lt,stack,max(max(stack)/2)))=NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, @Luis shot first but your answer is helpful too.

Comment: @Jigg That's ok and he deserved it totally as he led from your `bsxfun` code! I am just too happy to post something related to `bsxfun` :) Pretty interesting question too!